# How to override styles for material-ui TextField component without using the MUIThemeProvider?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

How would I hide / remove the underline in a TextField component **without** using the following code:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiInput: {
      underline: {
        '&:hover:not($disabled):before': {
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.7)',
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

I would like to do it with props and according to the docs: https://material-ui.com/api/input/

I should be able to change the underline prop, but it does not work.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
<TextField
    id="name"
    label="Name"
    value={this.state.name}
    margin="normal"
    InputProps={{disableUnderline: true}}
/>
```

How did I figure it out?

You have linked to the [`Input` documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/input/), which does indeed have a `disableUnderline` prop.

However, you are using a [`TextField` component](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/):

> It's important to understand that the text field is a simple
>   abstraction on top of the following components:
>
> - FormControl
> - InputLabel
> - Input
> - FormHelperText

If you look at the list of available props for `TextField`:

> InputProps - object - Properties applied to the Input element.

Comment: Hey man. Yeah I did figure that out already. Thanks anyways for the help!

Comment: when i use inputProps, the suggestions disappear for autocomplete free solo.

Answer (score 8):

With the most recent version of Material-UI this was the only way I could make this work:

```
<TextField InputProps={{classes: {underline: classes.underline}}} />

const styles = theme => ({
  underline: {
    '&:before': {
      borderBottomColor: colors.white,
    },
    '&:after': {
      borderBottomColor: colors.white,
    },
    '&:hover:before': {
      borderBottomColor: [colors.white, '!important'],
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to fix this issue..

```
<TextField InputProps={{classes: {underline: classes.underline}}} />

const styles = theme => ({
  underline: {
    '&:hover': {
      '&:before': {
        borderBottom: ['rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.7)', '!important'],
      }
    },
    '&:before': {
      borderBottom: 'rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.7)',
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

solving this slightly different but in the same vein as the accepted answer as I hit a typescript error attempting to use the `disableUnderline` on the component itself.

```js
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles'

export const componentTheme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiTextField: {
      defaultProps: {
        InputProps: {
          disableUnderline: true,
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way for solving using mui styled.

```
  const CssAutocomplete = styled(Autocomplete)({
     "& .MuiInput-underline:after": {
         borderBottomColor: "#CDCDCD",
      },
     "& .MuiInput-underline:before": {
         borderBottomColor: "#fff",
      },
     "& .MuiInput-underline:hover:before": {
         borderBottomColor: ["#fff", "!important"],
      },
    });
```