# How to pass custom props to styled components using Material UI and TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, material-ui, styled-components

I am using TypeScript(v4.2.3) and Material UI(v4.11.3), and trying to pass the custom props to `styled` component.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  IconButton,
  styled,
} from '@material-ui/core';

const NavListButton = styled(IconButton)(
 ({ theme, panelOpen }: { theme: Theme; panelOpen: boolean }) => ({
   display: 'inline-block',
   width: 48,
   height: 48,
   borderRadius: 24,
   margin: theme.spacing(1),
   backgroundColor: panelOpen ? theme.palette.secondary.dark : 'transparent',
 }),
);

...

const Component: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  return (
    <NavListButton panelOpen={true} />
  );
};
```

This works fine, but if I check the console, it faces an error.

```
Warning: React does not recognize the `panelOpen` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `panelopen` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
    at button
    at ButtonBase ...
```

How to get rid of this without using styled-components module, need to use `styled` from Material UI?

And also this is another similar question.

I wanted to add media queries to styled components, it says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'addRule' of null`.

```
const PrintableTableContainer = styled(TableContainer)(() => ({
  '@media print': {
    '@page': { size: 'landscape' },
  },
}));
```

[image]

I also tried this.

```
const PrintableTableContainer = styled(TableContainer)`
  @media print {
    @page { size: landscape }
  }
`;
```

But it also says

```
Argument of type 'TemplateStringsArray' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CreateCSSProperties<(value: string, index: number, array: readonly string[]) => unknown> | ((props: { theme: Theme; } & ((value: string, index: number, array: readonly string[]) => unknown)) => CreateCSSProperties<...>)'.
  Type 'TemplateStringsArray' is not assignable to type 'CreateCSSProperties<(value: string, index: number, array: readonly string[]) => unknown>'.
    Types of property 'filter' are incompatible.
...
```

Comment: Not possible to get rid of this?

Answer (score 2):

Just my 2 cents, hope the solution I provide can help you.

The main cause is the material-ui version, your project may mix up with version 4 and version 5.

**1st: Install material-ui v5**

- `@next` version = v5
- install material-ui and styled-engine to use styled-components

```
// npm
npm install @material-ui/core@next @material-ui/styled-engine-sc@next styled-components
npm install --save-dev @types/styled-components


// yarn 
yarn add @material-ui/core@next @material-ui/styled-engine-sc@next styled-components
yarn add --dev @types/styled-components
```

---

**2nd: Install react-app-rewired**

the default material-ui `styled-engine` is pointing to `emotion`, so we need to override the webpack config to refer to styled-components.

The [Official Doc](https://next.material-ui.com/guides/styled-engine/) explains how to use styled-components in material-ui:

For `create-react-app`, install `react-app-rewired`

```
// npm 
npm install --save-dev react-app-rewired customize-cra

// yarn
yarn add --dev react-app-rewired customize-cra
```

---

**3rd: Override webpack config**

The Offical example: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/next/examples/create-react-app-with-styled-components-typescript

- create `config-overrides.js`
- override styled-engine path to point to styled-engine-sc path

```js
// config-overrides.js
const { addWebpackAlias, override } = require('customize-cra');

module.exports = override(
  addWebpackAlias({
    '@material-ui/styled-engine': '@material-ui/styled-engine-sc',
  }),
);
```

---

**4th: Now you can use the material-ui with styled-components**

```js
import { IconButton, styled, TableContainer, Theme } from "@material-ui/core";

const NavListButton = styled(IconButton)(
  ({ theme, $panelOpen }: { theme?: Theme, $panelOpen: boolean }) => ({
    display: "inline-block",
    width: 48,
    height: 48,
    borderRadius: 24,
    margin: theme?.spacing(1),
    backgroundColor: $panelOpen ? theme?.palette.secondary.dark : "transparent"
  })
);

const PrintableTableContainer = styled(TableContainer)(() => ({
  "@media print": {
    "@page": { size: "landscape" }
  }
}));

...

<NavListButton $panelOpen={true} />
<PrintableTableContainer />
```

For the 1st question, `` React does not recognize the `panelOpen` prop on a DOM element. `` .

styled-components provides a **transient props - `$`** to avoid the custom props to pass to the DOM.

https://styled-components.com/docs/api#transient-props

---

**A [demo git repo](https://github.com/michael-vascue/text-material-ui-next/blob/master/src/App.tsx) for your reference and cross-checking in case you cannot make it work**

Comment: Thanks in advance! Actually, I didn't realize Material UI has the new version 5. I will give it a shot.

Comment: Tried all the steps and also tried the example from the mui/examples repo, the warning wont go. But this answer 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49613774/material-ui-react-does-not-recognize-the-underlinestyle-prop-on-a-dom-element

did solve it for me

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. In my case i had:

```
import styles from './MabSidebar.styles';
...
const Sidebar = styled(Box)(styles);
```

Solved it quick and dirty by using any:

```
const Sidebar = styled(Box)(styles as any);
```